# Return data from function in Node module

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm currently trying to create a Node module and I'm having difficulty returning the data from a function in my module. I've done some searching and reading but haven't been able to figure it out.

I'm using the request plugin to fetch some JSON data from an API and I want to return that data to my application to use. Here's my module code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var request = require('request');


exports.zipQuery = function(zip){

  request('http://api.smartystreets.com/zipcode?' + 'auth-id=XXXXX' + '&auth-token=XXXXX' + '&zipcode=' + zip, function(err, response, body){
    if(!err && response.statusCode == 200){
      return body;
    } else {
     return 'Error returning data';
    }   
  });  
};
```

Here's the module that I'm calling it in:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var zip = require('../ziplookup/index');

router.get('/', function(req,res){
  res.send(zip.zipQuery(46805));

});

module.exports = router;
```

I'm receiving all the JSON data fine, but I can't figure out how to return it to use it. Currently I just get undefined when I look at my console.

Thanks for your help! I'm a bit of a node/js novice so I appreciate it!

Comment: what do you have on the client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`zipQuery()` returns `undefined` because no `return` statement runs before the function finishes. This is because `request` is asynchronous, so you need a callback.

```
exports.zipQuery = function(zip, callback){
  request('http://api.smartystreets.com/zipcode?' + 'auth-id=XXXXX' + '&auth-token=XXXXX' + '&zipcode=' + zip, function(err, response, body){
    if(!err && response.statusCode == 200){
      callback(null, body); // invoke callback function with the value you want to pass back
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Error returning data'));
    }   
  });  
}

// elsewhere
var zipQuery = require('zipQuery').zipQuery;

zipQuery(98765, function(error, response) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error)
  } else {
    console.log(null, "We got a good response! " + response);
  }
});
```

Comment: Also, `return 'Error returning data';` is useless because the returned value is almost always ignored by the async function. The callback should follow the "error-first" format so that you can pass an Error object in case of error (null/undefined otherwise).

Comment: Thanks a lot @AlexWayne! That's exactly what I needed. Now I understand modules a bit better.

Comment: @AlexWayne - can you explain the callback(null,body) portion? Why the null?